# AJAX Not Updating Variable Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm firing an ajax call to get data to populate a select box.  When this box is changed, another ajax call is fired to populate the next select box.  This works great and when choosing an item from the 2nd box it populates two text boxes with data perfectly.

However,if you make new choices without refreshing the page, the 2nd select box fails to populate the text boxes.

Echoing the vars: I created the var 'list' to view the additional data coming in from the ajax to prove it was coming in correctly.

On the first ajax call:
The first echo of 'list' shows the expected content.
The second echo of 'list' shows the expected content.

On the second ajax call:
The first echo of 'list' shows the expected content.
The second echo of 'list' shows the content from the first call.

I've tried calling this at different times, in the done callback and the always callback.  I've tried adding in the success element of the ajax call and having that call a function with the required process and still the same thing - it doesn't update.

```
        $('#customer').change(function() {
            var selected = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/support/incs/worker/worker.getinfo.php',
                data: {info: "names", id: selected},
                dataType: 'json',
                encode: true,
                beforeSend: function() {
                }
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var list = data.additional;
                console.log(list);
                if(data.status == true) {
                    $('#name').html('<option disabled selected>Select a User</option>');
                    $('#name').append(data.payload);
                    $('#name').change(function() {
                        var nameid = $(this).val();
                        console.log(list);
                        $('#email').attr('placeholder', list[nameid]['email']);
                        $('#tel').attr('placeholder', list[nameid]['tel']);
                    })
                } else {

                }
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
            })
            .always(function(data) {

            });
        })
```

The data should refresh so when a choice is made it updates the text boxes accordingly. However because the list variable isn't getting updated, the code can't find the required array key in the 'list' var and errors out.

Console Output:

```
[Echo of returned data]
{status: true, payload: "<option value="4">Finga Ninja</option>", additional: {…}}additional: {4: {…}}payload: "<option value="4">Finga Ninja</option>"status: true__proto__: Object

[First echo of list]
{4: {…}}4: {email: "***@***.com", tel: "01202 789456"}__proto__: Object

[Second echo of list]
{4: {…}}4: {email: "***@***.com", tel: "01202 789456"}__proto__: Object

[Echo of returned data]
{status: true, payload: "<option value="5">Slooty Bartfast</option>", additional: {…}}additional: {5: {…}}payload: "<option value="5">Slooty Bartfast</option>"status: true__proto__: Object

[First echo of list]
5: {…}}5: {email: "***@***.com", tel: "01202 456123"}__proto__: Object

[Second echo of list]
{4: {…}}4: {email: "***@***.com", tel: "01202 789456"}__proto__: Object
staff_home:283 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (staff_home:283)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLSelectElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

Appended HTML block:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="customer">Customer</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="customer" name="customer">
                <?php echo $sCustomerList; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                <option disabled selected>Select a User</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-6">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="email">Email</label>
             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" disabled placeholder="">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="tel">Contact Number</label>
             <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" disabled placeholder="">
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a heads up you might get downvoted for exposing your users' email addresses. I would suggest obfuscating them for the purposes of the question

Comment: @OscarChambers given the email addresses in question, I'm pretty sure they've already been obfuscated :)

Comment: Please append the HTML.

Comment: We can't repro the issue. Give us a server response for instance.

Comment: They are indeed made up email addresses, at least for us.  Just needed some rubbish in the database!

Comment: I've already put the returned data, what else do you require?

HTML is fine - its just a couple of selects and textboxes and as stated, works the first time.  Its the JS that is the problem on the subsequent runs.

Comment: @James I want the html for the ids of the elements.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'll add now for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me the problem is:

1. You select a customer. the js adds an event listener to the `#name` select.
2. You select a name. the event listener is executed, suggests e-mail and tel.
3. You select an another customer. Then, a **new** event listener is added to the `#name` select. The previous **is not** removed.
4. You select a name. The old listener tries to read its `list` (in your example, `4: { ... }`, and access the **new** name ID (`5`) through it. Of course, it returns `undefined`. An attempt made to access this `undefined`'s properties, which cause an unhandled error - the js code is crashed, and the correct code (the new event listener) never executed.

That says you need to remove ('off', in jQuery's terminology) the old event listener when attaching a new. You have some options:

- Save it in a variable, and call `off()` on it.
- Save them in an array, in the case of (maybe) multiple event listeners, and off all of them.
- the easiest way: assume you don't have other, constant event listener to `#name`'s `change` event, you can, in jQuery, off all the `change` handlers, with `elem.off('change')`. See [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/off/).

  ```
  $('#customer').change(function() {
      var selected = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/support/incs/worker/worker.getinfo.php',
          data: {info: "names", id: selected},
          dataType: 'json',
          encode: true,
          beforeSend: function() {
          }
      })
      .done(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          var list = data.additional;
          console.log(list);
          if(data.status == true) {
              $('#name').html('<option disabled selected>Select a User</option>');
              $('#name').append(data.payload)
                .off('change'); // must be before the call to 'change()', for not offing the new handler.
              $('#name').change(function() {
                  var nameid = $(this).val();
                  console.log(list);
                  $('#email').attr('placeholder', list[nameid]['email']);
                  $('#tel').attr('placeholder', list[nameid]['tel']);
              })
          } else {

          }
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
          //console.log(data);
      })
      .always(function(data) {

      });
  })
  ```

Comment: Thank you, adding the .off works perfectly!  I'll have a read of the docs - learning day for me :)